# How to tail log files in Powershell for particular string

Tags: powershell, tail

We would like to tail several log files "live" in powershell for particular string. We have tried to use "get-content" command but without luck because everytime as a result we received only results from one file. I assume that it was caused by "-wait" parameter. If there is any other way to tail multiple files ? I heard about runspaces but still I don't know how to implement it.

Our sample script below

```
dir d:\test\*.txt -include *.txt | `
Get-Content -Wait | `
select-string "windows" | `
ForEach-Object {Write-EventLog -LogName Application -Source "Application error" -EntryType information -EventId 999 -Message $_}
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Use `get-childitem` instead of dir and remove the `-wait` switch, see if that works

Comment: Thank for quick response but that is not what I needed. I need to track several txt files in specific directory "live" and that's why i used "-wait" option.

Answer (score 2):

Might be slightly late to the party...

As per [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28567973/powershell-tail-multiple-files-command), we can use the following in a .ps1 file;

```
$ProgressPreference='SilentlyContinue'
Workflow My-Tail
{
    Param([string[]] $Path)

    foreach -parallel ($file in $path)
    {
        Get-Content -Path $file -Tail 1 -Wait
    }
}
```

This lets us tail multiple files, invoking in powershell like;

```
My-Tail (dir C:\Users\User\Documents\*.log)
```

All that's left then is to filter by the required string;

```
My-Tail (dir C:\Users\User\Documents\*.log) | Select-String -Pattern ".*ERROR.*"
```

This will tail all files ending in .log in Documents, outputting lines that contain the text 'ERROR'

Comment: This works perfectly for what I need except I can't tell which file is which when they're all being read at the same time. Is there a way to open each 'get-content' in its own window/instance?

Answer (score 0):

The only way I can think to do this is to create a bunch of jobs that run the command on each file. You can then receive the job output in a loop and changes in any of the files will be written to the screen:

```powershell
gci d:\test\*.txt | % { $sb = [scriptblock]::create("get-content -wait $_") ; start-job -ScriptBlock $sb }
while(1) { 
  $m = $(get-job | receive-job | select-string "searchstring") 
  if($m -ne $null) { 
     Write-EventLog -LogName Application -Source "Application error" -EntryType information -EventId 999 -Message $m
  }
  sleep 1 
}
```

Comment: Ok, but if there is a way to find specific word and generate an event in windows log ? I've asked about it because we wanted to monitor specific application for errors and write an event to logs, then our Nagios system will raise alarm.

Comment: Thank you but script returned an error                                                               Write-EventLog : Cannot validate argument on parameter 'Message'. The argument is null, empty, or an element of the arg
ument collection contains a null value. Supply a collection that does not contain any null values and then try the comm
and again.
At D:\FIX.ps1:4 char:112
+ ... d 999 -Message $m
+                    ~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Write-EventLog], ParameterBindingValidationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationError,Microsoft.

Comment: Have you run it without the `Write-EventLog` line to make sure the message is populated properly first?

Comment: No I've just run it almost exactly as you provided, I've only changed "searchstring" attribute and saved code as ps1. So what exactly should I do ?

Comment: Made another edit, actually need to check `$m` is not empty before attempting to write the event log. You may want to replace the `Write-EventLog ...` with `Write-Host $m` while you're testing. That will write the results to the screen.

Comment: Thank you for suggestion regarding screen results but like i said before we need to raise an alarm based on event ID. Now script returned small error At D:\FIX.ps1:4 char:18
+   if($m -ne $null)
+                  ~
Missing statement block after if ( condition ).
At D:\FIX.ps1:8 char:1
+ }
+ ~
Unexpected token '}' in expression or statement.

Comment: For some reason, even though it was there, I didnt see the opening brace of the if statement in the answer. I update the answer and removed a space after the ) and now it shows up. Try arco's code again. @Maciejka666... now i see i was edit fighting with arco

Comment: Yes, but you need to make sure the data is correct before you start sending it to the event log. I can't write you the perfect script without seeing what's coming out of your log files. TBH if you can't fix a missing curly brace on your own, you're going to really struggle with this.

Comment: @Matt, yes we were trying to do the same thing simultaneously, thanks.

Comment: Now I have recieved another error below. Generally in application log files there are lines, which consists of information regarding date,time and what operation was made by application. Sometime there is string "low memory" and such word we would like to monitor.   Write-EventLog : Cannot validate argument on parameter 'Message'. The argument is null, empty, or an element of the argument collection contains a null value. Supply a collectio
n that does not contain any null values and then try the command again.
At D:\Runspaces.ps1:5 char:115
+ ... d 999 -Message $_ +$m