# Powershell tail multiple files command

Tags: powershell

I can tail one file via the following command:

`Get-Content -Path C:\log1.txt -Tail 10 –Wait`

How do I extend this to multiple files, I have tried the following with no luck:

`Get-Content -Path C:\log1.txt,C:\log2.txt -Tail 10 –Wait`

This will only pick up updates from the first file, not the second.

Comment: The -wait switch is going to block the thread.  To -tail -wait multiple files at once, you're going to have to have multiple threads.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Based on @mjolinor's comment, I have come up with the following that appears to work,

```
Workflow My-Tail
{
    Param([string[]] $Path)

    foreach -parallel ($file in $path)
    {
        Get-Content -Path $file -Tail 1 -Wait
    }
}

My-Tail (dir C:\*.log -Include log1.txt,log2.txt)
```

However, this has some sort of progress bar that appears...

Comment: You can add `$ProgressPreference='SilentlyContinue'` in the script to suppress the progress bar.  I'm working on my own version that will also highlight and filter lines.  https://github.com/McLeopold/TailorPosh

Comment: A workflow cannot use recursion.
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParseException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : RecursiveWorkflowNotSupported

Comment: This is an old answer, but workflows are deprecated in PWSH 6.x+

Answer (score 3):

I can't speak to how efficient this is, but since I'm using PowerShell Core 7.1.3, I can't use Workflows or `ForEach -Parallel`, but I can use `ForEach-Object -Parallel`, so I tried it just to see what would happen...

```
Get-ChildItem -Path C:\ -Filter log*.txt |
    ForEach-Object -Parallel {
        Get-Content -Wait -Tail 10 -Path $_
    } -ThrottleLimit 30
```

In my case, I had 27 files I needed to monitor, so I chose a number just above that, and this seemed to work.

Just to be sure it was working, I used this, which will output the source file name before each line:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path C:\ -Filter log*.txt |
    ForEach-Object -Parallel {
        $file = $_;
        Get-Content -Wait -Tail 10 -Path $file |
            ForEach-Object { Write-Output "$($file.Name): ${_}" }
    } -ThrottleLimit 30
```

Comment: I made a [gist](https://gist.github.com/leblocks/e239b36a0a8e0164846b46d37e04c827) based on this answer, maybe it will be useful for someone

Comment: @MonsieurMerso if you're interested, I wrote a whole blog post about it: https://chadbaldwin.net/2022/04/04/powershell-monitoring-log-files

Comment: Amazing, I'll mention it in my gist

Comment: great post, I referenced it in a comment in the gist.

Answer (score 0):

I needed tailed output across multiple files and I wanted to try do it in one line,
here's what I eventually came up with:

```
gci *.txt -recurse | ForEach-Object  { Write-Output "$_`n" + $(Get-Content $_ -tail 5) + "`n" }
```

Its takes a recursive directory listing of all files named *.txt,
writes the file path to console,
then writes the last 5 lines to console.

I didn't need to follow the tails of the files, they weren't being actively written to.

Answer (score 0):

Incorporating @McLeopold's comment into @Cheetah's code

```
function Tail (
  [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)][string[]]$Files,
  [long]$Tail = 1
) {
  workflow TailWorkflow (
    [string[]]$Files,
    [long]$Tail
  ) {
    foreach -parallel ($File in $Files) {
      Get-Content -Tail $Tail $File -Wait
    }
  }

  $ProgressPreference='SilentlyContinue'
  TailWorkflow -Files $Files -Tail $Tail
}
```